# How to start REPL at the end of python script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, read-eval-print-loop

How can I start REPL at the end of python script for debugging? In Node I can do something like this:

```
code;
code;
code;

require('repl').start(global);
```

Is there any python alternative?

Comment: You can just go the other way, and import your script in a repl environment

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you execute this from the command prompt, just use `-i`:

```
➜ Desktop echo "a = 50" >> scrpt.py
➜ Desktop python -i scrpt.py 
>>> a
50
```

this invokes Python after the script has executed.

Alternatively, just set `PYTHONINSPECT` to `True` in your script:

```
import os
os.environ['PYTHONINSPECT'] = 'TRUE'
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use **pdb** (python debugger)

```
import pdb
print("some code")
x = 50
pdb.set_trace() # this will let you poke around... try "p x"
print("bye")
```